# Getting extra space in last line after file seek and zipping it

Tags: c#

Using below code I am using File seek and convert to result byte to compressed stream and generating the zip file,

```
public static async Task Get(string filename)
{
    byte[] result;
    byte[] compressedBytes;

    using (FileStream SourceStream = File.Open(filename, FileMode.Open))
    {
        SourceStream.Seek(20, SeekOrigin.Begin);

        result = new byte[SourceStream.Length];

        await SourceStream.ReadAsync(result, 0, (int)SourceStream.Length);
    }


    string fileName = "Export_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddhhmmss") + ".zip";

    using (var outStream = File.Create(fileName))
    {
        using (var archive = new ZipArchive(outStream, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true))
        {
            var fileInArchive = archive.CreateEntry("test.txt", CompressionLevel.Optimal);
            using (var entryStream = fileInArchive.Open())
            using (var fileToCompressStream = new MemoryStream(result))
            {
                fileToCompressStream.CopyTo(entryStream);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now when I unzip the resultant file has extra space. What's the reason for it and how to resolve it?

[image]

Comment: not able to add image, the last line of file has extra space

Comment: Shouldn't `result = new byte[SourceStream.Length];` be `result = new byte[SourceStream.Length - 20];` since you are offsetting the read by 20?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're seeking 20 bytes into the stream, but the length of your array is the complete length of the stream. Therefore the final 20 bytes in your array are being ignored.

The simple fix for this is just to allocate less space, and then only ask to read the reduced number of bytes:

```
result = new byte[SourceStream.Length - 20];
await SourceStream.ReadAsync(result, 0, result.Length);
```

Note that you're also assuming that a single call to `ReadAsync` will read all the data. That may be the case in many situations, but it's generally not a good idea to assume that about streams.

It would be simpler just to copy straight from the file stream to the compressed stream though, instead of reading the whole file into memory first:

```
public static async Task Get(string filename)
{
    string outputFile = "Export_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddhhmmss") + ".zip";

    using (var outStream = File.Create(outputFile))
    {
        using (var archive = new ZipArchive(outStream, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true))
        {
            var fileInArchive = archive.CreateEntry("test.txt", CompressionLevel.Optimal);
            using (var entryStream = fileInArchive.Open())
            using (var fileToCompressStream = File.Open(filename, FileMode.Open))
            {
                // Skip the first 20 bytes
                fileToCompressStream.Position = 20;
                fileToCompressStream.CopyTo(entryStream);
            }
        }
    }
}
```